# Match a sentence using pattern

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a program where I have to check if the input match a sentence/string which includes words and numbers using pattern compile. I dont know how many words there be.

This i what some of my code looks like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z][ \\t]*([0-9]*)");

sysln("                          P R O J E C T  P L A N N E R                          ");
sysln(" -------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        sysln("                                 Free Resources                                 ");
        sysln("                                                                                ");
        sys(" Enter the project name + the week number > ");
        String s = input.nextLine().trim();
        matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

        if (!matcher.matches()){
            sys(" Wrong format -- hit any key to continue > ");
            input.nextLine();
            continue;
        }
```

I have tried just to write Hallo 12, but it outputs the error message.

I found out that [a-zA-Z] only reads one letter, what should i write instead of [a-zA-Z] ?

Comment: Post some examples with their desired output and the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Regular expressions are your friend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Some examples would be really nice, but a sentence uses spaces to split words, so you could just use it. Something like: `/([a-zA-z])+[ :.,]/` could be a good starting point.

Comment: I have edit my question, i hope it's more clear now :D